# How can I use multiple DNS providers and have them be "valid"?

Tags: dns

I use my registrar's DNS offering, and am quite happy with it - but there is no API access to their system.

However, I would *like* to be able to also use my hosting provider's DNS system (which is API-accessible), so that when I spin-up and spin-down systems, I can add and delete them from DNS at the same time without needing to go to another service.

For example, my main domain might be `example.com`. When I spin-up a new service I want to run in that domain, I'd like to give it the DNS entry of `newservice.example.com` with my hosting provider's DNS.

*Registering* the DNS entry with my hosting provider is a snap - super easy, and pretty much idiot-proof.

*Navigating* to the new hostname, however, does not work. Nor does running `dig`, `nslookup`, etc.

How can I get the new services properly registered with my hosting provider's DNS *and* then be able to navigate to it by name later?

Comment: You need to contact your domain name registrar and have them change the records for which DNS servers are authoritative for that domain (from theirs, to your hosting provider's).  Having said that, this question is not on-topic or SU.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - it's not on-topic at SF :: SU is the best fit from what I can tell  of the SE family. Do you have a better locational suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to choose whether you want the registrar's name servers or the hosting provider's name servers to be authoritative for your domain name. When you purchase a domain name from a [domain name registrar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name_registrar), there is typically a configuration page for your domain where you specify the name servers that should be the authoritative name servers to perform the translation from domain name to IP address. By default, the registrar will normally set the name servers to its own DNS servers, but you have the option to set the name server IP addresses to others you prefer, which in this case would be your hosting provider.

However, there is the possibility that you might be able to have the hosting provider's and the registrar's DNS servers be authoritative for your domain. Some registrars provide the option to have their name servers be secondary name servers. E.g., GoDaddy states at [Enable Secondary DNS](https://www.godaddy.com/help/enable-secondary-dns-premium-dns-797)

> When setting up Secondary DNS, you select our nameservers as your
>   primary (master) or secondary (slave) nameserver set. If you designate
>   our nameservers as the master set, the DNS Manager makes all zone file
>   updates and the slaves (your nameserver set) pick them up. If you
>   designate us as the slave, then your own master nameservers make the
>   DNS updates, and you must configure them to send notifications to our
>   slave nameservers so they pick up the changes.

So it might be possible to use the servers from both with the hosting provider's servers as the master DNS servers for the domain; you could log into your account with the domain name registrar and check the settings page for your domain where you specify the name servers to see if you can make the hosting provider's name servers the primary ones and the registrar's servers the secondary ones then check to see if your hosting provider will allow you to set it's servers as the master servers and the registrar's as slave DNS servers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do what you want is to move *authoritative* DNS hosting to your (web? cloud?) hosting provider's DNS platform and then go to your registrar and change the DNS there to use the hosting provider.

You can poke the hosting API all day long with no effect if they do not *authoritatively* host your DNS zone.  The *only* place that has any effect on your zone contents is the primary authoritative DNS server, which currently is at your registrar.